# Set an AspectJ advise for static method

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop

I have written simple Aspect with primitive Pointcut and Advise method:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

  @Pointcut("execution(static * com.mtag.util.SomeUtil.someMethod(..))")
  public void someMethodInvoke() { }

  @AfterReturning(value = "someMethodInvoke())", returning = "comparisonResult")
  public void decrementProductCount(List<String> comparisonResult) {
    //some actions
  }
}
```

I have following Spring annotation-based application config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AppConfig { 
  //...
}
```

And utility class in com.mtag.util package:

```
public class SomeUtil {
  static List<String> someMethod(List<String> oldList, List<String> newList) {
    //...
  } 
}
```

but when I call

```
SomeUtil.someMethod(arg1, arg2);
```

in unit test I can see that method call is not intercepted and my @AfterReturning advise is not working.

But if i change someMethod() type to instance (non-static) method, pointcut to

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.mtag.util.SomeUtil.someMethod(..))")
```

and manage SomeUtil bean by Spring by adding @Component annotation and call target metod like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfig.class}, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class SomeUtilTest {

    @Autowired
    private SomeUtil someUtil;

    @Test
    public void categoriesDiffCalc() {
        List<String> result = someUtil.someMethod(...);
    }
}
```

Everything is OK.

In what way I can set an Advice for static method?

Comment: `@AfterReturning(value = "someMethodInvoke())"` you have an extra bracket

Comment: @izhamoidsin, is the answer provided (by me) accepted. Or this one is incorrect?

Answer (score 10):

Actually there is no solutions to intercept static methods using auto proxy in spring framework. 
You should use the LWT AspectJ solution.

In a nutshell you should use the same annotations but with some additional configuration.

1) add to the spring context file next line:

```
<context:load-time-weaver/>
```

(may be in your situation it is not necessary)

2) unfortunately you should also add META-INF/aop.xml. Example:

```
<weaver>
    <include within="com.example.ClassA"/> <!-- path to concrete class -->
    <include within="com.log.* "/> <!—- path to aspects package -->
</weaver>
<aspects>
    <aspect name="com.log.AspectA"/>
</aspects>
```

3) when starting JVM the argument

```
-javaagent:${PATH_TO_LIB }/aspectjweaver.jar
```

should be added.

So this solution is rather laborious.

For more information read 7.8.4 chapter here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch07s08.html

Comment: Good answer, Eugene. I do not even think this solution is laborious. Once it is set up it will work forever. :-) Anway, if you want to avoid extra runtime configuration you can still use compile-time weaving.

Comment: yep, I meant that this solution is laborious depends on intercepting non-static methods, but for me it was laborious to investigate. =)

Comment: @kriegaex Do you mean that we can also use compile-time weaving with Spring AOP to intercept static methods?

Comment: @Kwadz, you can use CTW with AspectJ, then you do not need Spring AOP anymore. But you could still use Spring AOP for other aspects then, if that was your question.

Comment: @kriegaex In fact I wanted to know if Spring AOP alone supports CTW, and if this allows to intercept static methods.

Comment: Spring AOP does not need to support AspectJ CTW because the latter is independent from Spring. And yes, AspectJ supports intercepting static methods. P.S.: Spring AOP has special support for AspectJ LTW, see [Spring AOP manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj). But as I said, CTW is also possible, with or without Spring.

Comment: @kriegaex does aspectJ allow CTW with static methods?

Comment: Didn't I already answer this question just in the comment above? Yes, it does support static method weaving with CTW. The manual would also tell you, BTW. Good luck!